# generating sports league table from results table

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, count

I have a table containing all teams in a league's fixtures and results. I am attempting to generate a standings table from the results. I thought I had it working but upon manually calculating the standings it did not match the table that MySql  output.

```
$query_away = " Select teams.team_name,
    SUM(if(fixtures.away_team_score > fixtures.home_team_score,3,0)) AS W,
    SUM(IF(fixtures.away_team_score = fixtures.home_team_score,1,0)) AS D,
    SUM(IF(fixtures.away_team_score < fixtures.home_team_score,0,0)) AS L
FROM teams
 INNER JOIN fixtures ON teams.team_name = fixtures.home_team 
 GROUP BY fixtures.home_team
 ORDER BY W DESC";
```

It seams to be assigning unearned 3 pts to teams that did not win. Is there a simpler way to achieve this or a way to fix the code I have?
To summarize, I am attempting to count the amount of times an away team out scores a home team and assign 3 pts for that. 1 pt for tying with an opponent on 0 for losing.

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85813/1

**Edit**

this query is repeated twice once for home standings and once for away standings. joining the away query on `away_team` fixed the unearned 3pts problem however it would help if i could achieve the standings from one query. code below.

```
$fullTable = [];
$sortedTable = [];

$query_away = " Select teams.team_name,
    SUM(if(fixtures.away_team_score > fixtures.home_team_score,3,0)) AS W,
    SUM(IF(fixtures.away_team_score = fixtures.home_team_score,1,0)) AS D,
    SUM(IF(fixtures.away_team_score < fixtures.home_team_score,0,0)) AS L
 FROM teams
 INNER JOIN fixtures ON teams.team_name = fixtures.away_team 
 GROUP BY fixtures.away_team
 ORDER BY W DESC";



$query_home = " Select teams.team_name, 
    SUM(if(fixtures.home_team_score > fixtures.away_team_score,3,0)) AS W,
    SUM(IF(fixtures.home_team_score = fixtures.away_team_score,1,0)) AS D,
    SUM(IF(fixtures.home_team_score < fixtures.away_team_score,0,0)) AS L
 from teams
 inner join fixtures on teams.team_name = fixtures.home_team 
 GROUP BY fixtures.home_team
 order by W desc";


$home_result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_home);
$away_result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_away);
echo'<table><tr><th>Home Table</th><th>W</th><th>D</th><th>L</th><th>Pts</th></tr>';
if (!$home_result) {
    echo 'no result';
} else {
    //print_r(mysqli_fetch_array($result));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($home_result)) {
        $pts = $row['W'] + $row['D'];
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['team_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['W'] / 3 . "</td><td>" . $row['D'] . "</td><td>" . $row['L'] . "</td><td>" . $pts . "</td><tr>";
        $homeTeam = $row['team_name'];
    $fullTable["$homeTeam"] = $pts;
}
    echo'</table>';
}
```

Comment: an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with example data would help.

Comment: You're joining to the teams table on teams.team_name = fixtures.home_team. That means when you do the `if away_team_score > home_team_score`, you will be adding 3 for the team that loses.

Comment: @Dagon fiddle added see Q.

Comment: @Don'tPanic can you explain this

Comment: I think if you join it on team_name = away_team instead you should get the results you expect.

Comment: On a side note, are teams not supposed to get any points if they win or tie as the home team? That's what it sounds like you have in mind from your question, but it seems strange to me.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that solved it if you would like to add an answer. and they do but it is handled in a separate query but if you know a waw i can do it in one i am open to suggestions. thanks

Comment: It seems like it should be possible to do it in one. You could edit the question to include that if you want. I'm about to be on the road for a bit so I won't be able to answer properly just yet.

Comment: @Don'tPanic will do Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should get three points for victories both home and away at the same time. Only one sum is needed for ties because it does not matter if the team is home or away. No sum is really needed for losses, because you'd just be adding up a bunch of zeros anyway.

```
SELECT teams.team_name,
    SUM(if(teams.team_name = fixtures.away_team 
        AND fixtures.away_team_score > fixtures.home_team_score,3,0)) 
    + SUM(if(teams.team_name = fixtures.home_team 
        AND fixtures.home_team_score > fixtures.away_team_score,3,0)) AS W,
    SUM(IF(fixtures.away_team_score = fixtures.home_team_score,1,0)) AS D,
    0 AS L
FROM teams
INNER JOIN fixtures ON teams.team_name = fixtures.home_team 
    OR teams.team_name = fixtures.away_team
GROUP BY teams.team_name
ORDER BY W DESC
```